# Can we drive an led from output port of TCA6424ARGJR IC?

Tags: led, digital-logic, diodes, switches, gpio

I am using TCA6424ARGJR IC so from its output port 24 I need to keep an led, which glow when there is high.

Can we drive an led from output port of TCA6424ARGJR IC?

I have connected as shown in IMG.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the datasheet? What does it say for hi- and low-level output currents?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can light a LED, but not at 30mA, because it exceeds the recommended value.

Answer (score 0):

Each (P) Port can source 25mA from Vcc, which may not be enough for the 30mA that you want in the diagram. Make sure you size the resistor so no more that 25mA (maybe a little lower also, like 24mA) so that the ratings in the datasheet are not violated.

Also make sure that the sum of the current from all the P ports does not exceed 160mA

[image]
Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TCA6424A

Answer (score 0):

You can drive up to 160mA as a high side LED driver with Current limiting R.

But that doesn't mean you should. Nor does it mean you should use 30mA the common 5mm Absolute max for an indicator.

With LED indicators up to 10kmcd, all you need is about 2 mA. 30mA would be blinding. But if you chose an old 100 mcd RED LED then I can see 20mA is OK, but 30mA is not recommended unless you are just playing around as the junction will be burning hot then.

Ignore the Port Out max current. That is just for Logic levels. 0.8V/25mA max indicates the minimum RdsOn is 32 Ohms for the driver.